# What are the various js files that are loaded for an Angular 2+ App in the browser initially

Tags: angular

[image]

These are the files loaded for my angular app in the browser, I want to know what each of these js files represent, I know that scripts.js file includes all the scripts that we add in angular.json file. Likewise what are the other js files?

Comment: main.js is the transpiled version of main.ts.

Comment: same case with polyfills.ts

Comment: Thanks for the comment. In particular am not finding any info on styles.js and runtime.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
main.js = your bundled application 

vendor.js = Any third-party library or "vendor" code your source is dependent on.

styles.js = contains a script to load all the style rules contained in your styles.scss

polyfills.js = dependencies bundled (@angular, RxJS) 

runtime.js = all the code webpack needs to connect your modularized application while it's running in the browser. 
It contains the loading and resolving logic needed to connect your modules as they interact. 
This includes connecting modules that have already been loaded into the browser as well as logic to lazy-load the ones that haven't.
```